# cx_freeze issue python3 setup file

Tags: python, cx-freeze

How do I add `{'include_files':includefiles}` to the options field down below?
All I get is an error in python.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable as cxExecutable
import platform
import sys


# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

build_exe_options = {
"include_msvcr": True
}


WIN_Target = cxExecutable(
    script='PlayTubeInstaller.pyw',
    base=base,
#    if sys.platform == 'win32': base = 'Win32GUI'
    icon="Icon.ico"
)



includefiles = [ 'Icon.ico' , 'PlayTube.ipa' , 'libmobiledevice/' ]

setup(
    name = 'Installer',
    version = '0.1',
    description = 'A general enhancement utility',
    author = 'Steve Jobs',
    options = {'build_exe': build_exe_options},
    executables=[WIN_Target]
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
build_exe_options = {
"include_msvcr": True,
"includes": [ 'Icon.ico' , 'PlayTube.ipa' , 'libmobiledevice/' ],
}
```

Comment: it was missing a comma, try again.  Also it's usually helpful to actually paste the exact error traceback.